# ACF compare dates from wordpress query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF custom field with text as type but it stores date (string format), I have to search all custom post type between two dates and I don't know how to handle this.

```
$query = array(
    'key' => 'registration_date',
    'value' => array($startDate, $endDate),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'date'
);
```

Is not working because custom field value is a string format and comparison is not possible.
How can i search post type between $startDate and $endDate then?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that date comparaison only works with format YYYYMMDD, if you use something else like "DD.MM.YYYY" this will not work.

Your options are :
1. storing YYYYMMDD
2. using custom mysql queries.